# Facing ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, pytest

```
|__package
|__utils
  |__actions
    |__business_logics
      |__business_logics.py
    |__tests
      |__test.py
```

`This is my project structure, and my current working dir is **tests**, which is under the **actions**, Here I need to import the **business_logics.py** inside **test.py**

while importing the **business_logics.py** inside my **test.py** facing some issue.
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package``

`from ..business_logics import business_logics`

this how i am trying to import the file inside my working dir.

Answer (score 0):

> my current working dir is `tests`,

That won't work. Don't change your working directory, but just run e.g.

```
pytest utils/tests
```

from your project's root directory instead to run only the tests in that directory.

Comment: Then which dir I need to mention in `pytest.ini`

Comment: Um, I don't think you need to configure anything in `pytest.ini` at all.

Comment: pytest utils/actions/test, I Need to run like this, But the issue is, while running this, 
In business_logics.py, I have imported some files from utils and other dir too,  so getting the same issue, what i have metion above ( E   ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package )

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
project_folder
├── package
│   └── utils
│       └── actions
│           └── business_logics
│               └── business_logics.py
└── tests
    └── test.py
```

To import business_logics.py from test.py, you can use an absolute import instead of a relative import. Modify your import statement in test.py as follows:

```
from package.utils.actions.business_logics.business_logics import ...
```

Replace the ellipsis (...) with the specific names you want to import from `business_logics.py`. By using the absolute import, you can directly specify the full package path to access the module.

Make sure that your working directory is set to the tests directory, or you can execute `test.py` from the project root directory. This will allow the interpreter to find and import the module correctly.

Comment: This won't work if OP's working directory is `tests`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to address.

1. To use relative imports, you must be at a directory level from which you can traverse all imported directories. In your case, you should be in `actions/` or higher.
2. Your import should be as follows

```
from ..business_logics.business_logic import <class/function>
```